# How to load JavaScript object or call object method dynamically?

Tags: javascript

Please look into the example code below

```
var temp = {
    load:function(x) {
        //using x need to initialized an object or call a function
        //example object name xConf.We need to do concatenate also
        var obj=x+'Conf';
        new obj();          // not working
        global.obj.add()    // not working
    }
};
```

Looking forward for your suggestions.

Comment: x is a string and object name prefix

Comment: use         var obj= eval(x+'Conf');

Comment: use bracket notation: `global[obj]()` and `global[obj].add()`

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
global[x + 'Conf'].addConfig();
```

Not that this assumes that the object is available in the global namespace.

Comment: Since he use `global` he probably use node.js.

Comment: @jcubic Right, switched to global. That should work as far as I can understand?

Comment: @OptimusCrime looks like yes [link](https://jsfiddle.net/gc9jb8w1/)

Comment: Following code working

var a = x+'Conf';
global[a].addConfig();

Comment: @manashb That is more or less the same as my answer. I've updated my answer to reflect your use case in more details.